# Quadcopters compatible with ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i am new here !I just got my  dissertation on ros system and i would like to buy a cheap quadcopter to work with!
Any ideas!
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197949/quadcopters-compatible-with-ros/) by [ioannis.kats](https://answers.ros.org/users/20891/ioannis.kats/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Package [ardrone_autonomy](http://wiki.ros.org/ardrone_autonomy) works with realistic model Parrot AR. arone, also check http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone

---

Originally posted by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) with karma: 115 on 2014-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2